# Github "PUT" request in Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, github, android-asynctask, github-api

```
URL url = new URL(link);
connection1 = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
String auth = username + ":" + access_token;
String token = "Basic " + (Base64.encodeToString(auth.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP));
connection1.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "0");
connection1.setRequestMethod("PUT");
connection1.setRequestProperty("Authorization", token);
connection1.setDoOutput(true);
connection1.connect();
```

I'm trying to update the following page of my github account using android studio. This code works for "GET" request but not for "PUT". My access token works with postman so it should be fine. My url link follows the GitHub api guide with the format:

> https://api.github.com/user/following/user_to_follow

I put the code in an AsyncTask and I do not receive any error from android studio. What might be the potential problem?

Comment: Do you mean that the PUT request is working in Postman? Have you checked the PUT? Also saying that there are no errors, are you sure that you don't just skip/ignore them in your code? Show how you handle errors

Comment: Use networking libraries like Retrofit. Asynctasks for networking are slow, hard to maintain and brittle.

Answer (score 0):

Use retrofit with proper annotation. And debug the code set by step.The you get the  problem.